# iOS Facebook Login with SDK 4.12

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am banging my head against getting Facebook Login to work wen upgrading to SDK 4.12.  It was working fine in our (very) old 3.x implementation.

I have followed every bit of documentation I can find, and have re-checked my code over and over.  Hopefully someone can provide some insight!

My issue is, it simply does not allow for a 1 click single sign on.  When the FBSDKLoginButton is clicked, it always brings up the Facebook web dialog to enter credentials.  This is being run on an actual device, with the Facebook app installed and logged in.

Why can I not get it to simply allow access without signing in to Facebook?

Simple code is as follows:

```
FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
loginButton.readPermissions =
@[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];
loginButton.delegate = self;
```

Delegate callbacks all working fine.. the only issue having to enter user/password on the Facebook pop up.

(My device IS logged into Facebook in it's settings as well.)

Thank You!

Comment: In iOS 9 and later web dialog is used. Doesn't matter if you are signed in in the app or not

Comment: That's a real bummer.  I thought the point was to make it a nice user experience... in iOS9 with the old Facebook SDK, it works seamless.

Comment: It is a nicer user experience. In iOS9 every app switch pops a dialog that the user have to approve. If they don't a approve they get in a strange state. We didn't just switch it we tested a huge amount of things. And they will only be asked for email/password once. Then the webview remembers it

Comment: Understood.  So if a user has already logged in to Facebook via Safari, will those credentials be available to the Facebook login, and no credentials be needed? (I think this document is saying that.. https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/10/29/Facebook-Login-iOS9/).

Comment: Correct. So they only need to login once

Comment: thank you for the clarification.  My feelings on this are the same as those left under that article.  This is in no way easier for the user whatsoever, and goes against the idea of using Facebook login.  With a large blind user base, we keep useless interaction with the app to a minimum. This flies in the face of that. I personally have had the Facebook app on my device for years.. and am apparently not logged in via safari, so the assumption that most people are is incorrect.  Especially when private browsing completely breaks this solution.  That being said, thanks for the concrete answer.

Comment: We tested it and it preformed better than app switching. We don't just change stuff because it is fun and we assume it will be better or worse

Comment: I get that. and I know things change. What about users on private browsing in safari? Is there a workaround for that, or will they be prompted to log in when performing any Facebook function in the app?  (move your answer comment to an answer and I will mark it resolved.) Thanks.

Comment: I haven't tried private browser so I don't know what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to this for those who like the old way.. use SDK 4.5.1.  It has the Facebook login flow as it was intended.  You may lose a few of the newest features available in 4.6, but it has solved all of our issues.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/downloads